# Filtering across multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr

Based on this data:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  grp = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), each = 3),
  wave = rep(1:3, times = 3),
  var1 = c(1, -2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1, 4, -5),
  var2 = c(-1, 2, 3, -4, 5, 6, 1, 4, 5)
)

df
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#>   grp    wave  var1  var2
#>   <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1     1    -1
#> 2 a         2    -2     2
#> 3 a         3     3     3
#> 4 b         1     4    -4
#> 5 b         2     5     5
#> 6 b         3     1     6
#> 7 c         1     1     1
#> 8 c         2     4     4
#> 9 c         3    -5     5
```

How can I filter out groups (`grp`) that have a negative value in either `var1` or (or both) `var2` columns only when `wave` is between 1 and 2. Using this data, only data of group *c* would be returned. I tried something like the folowing, but no succes.

```r
df %>%
  group_by(grp) %>%
  filter(across(contains("var"), ~ .x[between(wave, 1, 2)] > 0))
#> Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
#> x Input `..1` must be of size 3 or 1, not size 2.
#> ℹ Input `..1` is `across(contains("var"), ~.x[between(wave, 1, 2)] > 0)`.
#> ℹ The error occurred in group 1: grp = "a".
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0.9001)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> df %>% group_by(grp) %>% filter(!any((var1<0|var2<0) & between(wave,1,2)))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   grp [1]
  grp    wave  var1  var2
  <chr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1 c         1     1     1
2 c         2     4     4
3 c         3    -5     5
>
```